Coloring 4 walls of a room with 4 colours such that no adjacent walls have same colours.
Question
In how many ways, 4 walls of a room be coloured with 4 colours (R,G,B,Y) such that no adjacent walls have same colours.
Attempt
Let (ABCD) be walls in clockwise order, D is adjacent to A and C. Now it is possible to color A in 4 ways, B in 3 ways, C in 3 ways, and D in 2 ways. Thus there are 72 ways in total.
Is this correct? At different different places, I am finding different different answers.

What if $A$ and $C$ have the same color?

If, say, $A$ is painted $R$ and both $B,D$ are painted $G$ then there are three choices for $C$.

Your question is a special case of computing the chromatic polynomial of a cycle graph.

Here are two different human solutions, and the quick computer check.

$\bf (1)$ Let us fix some painting of walls. Then a number of $n(w)$ different colors are involved, $n(w)$ is a number among $2,3,4$. For each $w$ let $\pi(w)$ be the pattern involved, which is computed as follows.

The color of wall $A$ is denoted by $X$. If this color occurs once more (and in this case it is wall $D$), than its position is also denoted by $X$.
The color of wall $B$ is $Y$. If this color occurs once more (and in this case it is wall $D$), than its position is also denoted by $X$.
If the color of wall $C$ is not $X$, we use the letter $Z$ for it.
If the color of wall $D$ is not $Y$, we use the letter $W$ for it.
The pattern $\pi(w)$ is then the word built with the colors of the walls, using the different letters $X,Y,Z,W$ as above.

The following patterns are the only possible patterns:

for $n(w) = 4$ there is only $XYZW$,
for $n(w) = 3$ there are the possibilities $XYXW$ and $XYZY$,
for $n(w) = 2$ there is only $XYXY$.

Now we count, according to the patterns and obtain:

for the pattern $XYZW$ there are $4$ choices for $X$, then $3$ choices for $Y\ne X$, then $2$ choices for $W\ne X,Y$, and the remained one choice for $Z$. We obtain $4!=24$ solutions.
for the pattern $XYXW$ there are $4$ choices for $X$, then $3$ choices for $Y\ne X$, then $2$ choices for $W\ne X,Y$. Again $24$ solutions. The other pattern, $XYZY$, is a cyclic cousin, so further $24$ solutions.
finally for $XYXY$ there are $4$ choices for $X$, then $3$ choices for $Y\ne X$, we obtain $12$ solutions.

Totally there are $24+24+24+12=12(2+2+2+1)=12\cdot 7=84$ solutions.

$\bf (2)$ Inclusion+Exclusion like argument. Let $A_{ij}$ be the set of all painting of walls, where the walls $i,j$ (now among $0,1,2,3$ not $A,B,C,D$) have the same color. How big (cardinality) is $A_{01}\cup A_{12}\cup A_{23}\cup A_{30}$? It is convenient to denote by $B_i$ the set $A_{i,i+1}$.
The indices $i,j$ are always considered modulo four.

$B_0$ has cardinality $4^3$, for the pattern $XXYZ$ with independent, (here and below) possibly repeating $X,Y,Z$. Same for the other $B_i$.
Intersection of two sets among the four $B_0,B_1,B_2,B_3$ are of two types.
Intersection of two "consecutive" sets in the list, typically $B_0\cap B_1$, the pattern is $XXXY$, or of two "opposite" sets, typically $B_0\cap B_2$, the pattern is $XXYY$. In each case there are $4^2$ possibilities.
Intersection of three sets among the four $B_0,B_1,B_2,B_3$ are of one type, $B_0\cap B_1\cap B_2$, only one pattern is available, $XXXX$, four matches.
The one intersection of all four $B_0,B_1,B_2,B_3, B_4$ leads to the pattern $XXXX$, four matches.

Putting all together, in the union there are:
$$
|B_0\cup B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3| = 
\binom 41\cdot 4^3 -
\binom 42\cdot 4^2 +
\binom 43\cdot 4^1 -
\binom 44\cdot 4^1 
=
4^4-\underbrace{(6\cdot16 - (4-1)\cdot 4)}_{=84}\ .
$$
possibilities.
So from all the possible cases, only $84$ have no (cyclicly) consecutive walls painted in the same color.

$\bf (3)$ Computer count, sage code:
C = list('RGBY')    # list of four colors
count = len([w for w in cartesian_product([C, C, C, C])
             if  w[0] != w[1] and w[1] != w[2] 
             and w[2] != w[3] and w[3] != w[0]])

And we get 84 when printing the count.

Same answer as dan fulea, just explained differently:
The question wondered if the following was the correct answer to the wall coloring counting problem:

Let (ABCD) be walls in clockwise order, D is adjacent to A and C. Now it is possible to color A in 4 ways, B in 3 ways, C in 3 ways, and D in 2 ways. Thus there are 72 ways in total.

This count is not quite correct because if A and C are colored with the same color, then D can be colored in $3$ ways not $2$.  So let’s count the wall colorings in two cases:
Case 1:  A and C are colored the same.
It is possible to color A in $4$ ways, B in $3$ ways, C in $1$ way, and D in $3$ ways.
There are $4 \times 3 \times 1 \times 3=36$ ways in this case.
Case 2:  A and C are colored differently.
It is possible to color A in $4$ ways, B in $3$ ways, C in $2$ ways, and D in $2$ ways.
There are $4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 2=48$ ways in this case.
So in total there are $36+48=84$ ways to color the walls.
